# Thread sleep, does not do

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sleep

I have problem with Thread in Java. I want to make when the button (bt1) is clicked to  set Background to picture, then wait for 5 seconds and the set Background of the same button to pic. The problem is that the first picture has never been set. The program just wait 5 seconds and set picture2. Here is the code.

```
bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override

    public void onClick(View v) {
          bt1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.picture);
              try
                 {
                   Thread.sleep(5000);
              }
              catch( InterruptedException e )
              {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
          bt1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pic);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Sleeping in a UI thread is a bad idea in just about every UI framework I've ever seen. I suspect you want a timer.

Comment: Sounds to me that you are pausing a foreground UI thread.  You have to fork a background thread to change it.

Comment: Because you set the picture, then sleep the UI thread, it cannot update.  Immediately after you wake it, it then changes it and updates.  As others have said, timer, asynctask, runnable, anything except sleep.  (sleep sucks 99% of the time anyway, this is not one of the 1% :)

Comment: Sleeping *just about anywhere* is typically a bad idea.  This, for example, would be better accomplished by setting a timer than by tying up a thread's worth of resources for 5 seconds, even if it's just a background thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It because you are running everything on main UI thread. Never use sleep with UI thread.

here is code for you.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            bt1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.picture);
            Thread thread = new Thread()
            {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                            Thread.sleep(5000);
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){public void run()
                            {
                                bt1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pic);
                            }});    

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            thread.start();


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 9):

**Never, ever sleep the user interface thread!**

Comment: @Gray: of course, it makes the OS think the process is unresponsive.

Comment: Care to expand on your answer to provide more information to the user.  Right now it's a comment.  See @Patricia's answer.

Comment: @Gray: I'm with you - and feel free to downvote - but the problem here is so serious it requires a rethink from scratch, and a very bold answer.

Comment: The point of answering these sorts of questions dude is to provide information for posterity.  You want to explain to an obviously junior programmer the concept that they are missing.  Why should you never sleep a user interface thread?  What does it mean?  What's the right way to do it?

Comment: @Gray: perhaps we should move into chat, but, without trying to be patronising, I want the programmer to never sleep the UI thread again. I'm not expecting this answer to be the accepted one but I believe in its legitimacy.

Comment: I have no objection to @Bathsheba copying from my answer to enhance this answer. I think the perfect answer would combine the bold "Never" sentence with the explanation of why it is such a bad idea, and caused the observed symptoms.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that you are sleeping in the thread that handles reacting to GUI events. While that thread sleeps, the GUI is dead. You need to do something else to get your five second delay, such as using a Timer to create a new event in 5 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    bt1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.picture); 
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                bt1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.picture);

            }
        }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: +1 for using a better tool for the job, rather than abusing `sleep`.  -1 for a code dump with no explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Use countdowntimer

```
new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

 }

 public void onFinish() {
      bt1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.picture);

 }
}.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Handlder.PostDelayed()`, and never do the time-consuming operation in UI Thread such as sleep, network, datebase...

Answer (score 0):

Why not use scheduler?Here is a possible implementation

```
bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override

public void onClick(View v) {
      bt1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.picture);
         ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors
            .newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
             bt1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pic);
        }
    }, 5, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      bt1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pic);
    }
});
```

}

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. It really helped me a lot. Now it works just as I wanted.